# How do I use write.csv in a for loop to use the original file name and a suffix to save my results to file?

Tags: r, csv, save

I am using a loop to run through a folder of files and extract datapoints. The main part of my code works, but i am havign issues getting it to save. I keep getting this Error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : invalid 'open' argument
```

Can you help me please? My original filenames are in the format "SpeciesName_loc.csv", I would like to save the results as "SpeciesName_tavg.csv" or "SpeciesName_prec.csv".

Here is the code I tried most recently. Nothign has worked. Some codes have saved but with NA_prec.csv or NA_tavg.csv, but not with the proper species name.

```
PREC <- "D:/RED LAPTOP BACKUP/DRENNAN R/PALEOCLIMATE_PROJECT/PREC_2023"
TEMP <- "D:/RED LAPTOP BACKUP/DRENNAN R/PALEOCLIMATE_PROJECT/TEMP_2023"
FILES <- "D:/RED LAPTOP BACKUP/DRENNAN R/PALEOCLIMATE_PROJECT/SPECIES_LOC_2023"
psuf <- "_prec"
tsuf <- "_tavg"

species <-list.files(FILES, pattern = '.csv', full.names = TRUE)

for (i in species){
media <- read.csv(i)
clim1 <- media$lon
clim2 <- media$lat
clim1lon <- c(clim1)
clim2lat <- c(clim2)
df <- data.frame(x= clim1lon, y= clim2lat)

prec.data <- df 
prec.data$Jan <- extract(prec1, df)
prec.data$Feb <- extract(prec2, df)
prec.data$Mar <- extract(prec3, df)
prec.data$Apr <- extract(prec4, df)
prec.data$May <- extract(prec5, df)
prec.data$Jun <- extract(prec6, df)
prec.data$Jul <- extract(prec7, df)
prec.data$Aug <- extract(prec8, df)
prec.data$Sep <- extract(prec9, df)
prec.data$Oct <- extract(prec10, df)
prec.data$Nov <- extract(prec11, df)
prec.data$Dec <- extract(prec12, df)
write.csv(prec.data, path = "PREC", gsub('loc.csv', 'prec.csv', i), row.names = FALSE)

temp.data <- df 
temp.data$Jan <- extract(temp1, df)
temp.data$Feb <- extract(temp2, df)
temp.data$Mar <- extract(temp3, df)
temp.data$Apr <- extract(temp4, df)
temp.data$May <- extract(temp5, df)
temp.data$Jun <- extract(temp6, df)
temp.data$Jul <- extract(temp7, df)
temp.data$Aug <- extract(temp8, df)
temp.data$Sep <- extract(temp9, df)
temp.data$Oct <- extract(temp10, df)
temp.data$Nov <- extract(temp11, df)
temp.data$Dec <- extract(temp12, df)
write.csv(temp.data, path = "TEMP", gsub('loc.csv', 'tavg.csv', i), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Replace `path = "TEMP", gsub('loc.csv', 'tavg.csv', i)` with `file = file.path("TEMP", gsub('loc.csv', 'tavg.csv', i))`

Comment: If you look at the `?write.csv` help page you'll see that it's arguments (in order) are `x` for the data to write, `file` for the file name, and then `append` for whether or not the data should be appended to the bottom of the file or overwritten. There is no `path` argument.

Comment: `write.csv` does not have a `path=` argument. It's named `file=`. See the `?write.csv` help page. Can you print out the value of `gsub('loc.csv', 'tavg.csv', i)` just to see what it looks like? Show us `dput(head(species))` so we can see what your actual values look like.

Answer (score 1):

Your second and third arguments likely need to be combined into a path. The call fails because of a few things:

1. `write.csv` takes `file=`, not `path=`;
2. it cannot write to a directory, so `file="TEMP"` (inferring that `"TEMP"` is a local directory) cannot work; and
3. your third (unnamed) argument is being applied to the `append=` argument, which should be logical.

Instead, try

```r
write.csv(temp.data, file = file.path("TEMP", gsub('loc.csv', 'tavg.csv', i)), row.names = FALSE)
```

From [`?write.csv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html), the args (and first few descriptions) are:

```
Usage:

     write.table(x, file = "", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
                 eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE,
                 col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"),
                 fileEncoding = "")
     
     write.csv(...)
     write.csv2(...)

Arguments:

       x: the object to be written, preferably a matrix or data frame.
          If not, it is attempted to coerce 'x' to a data frame.

    file: either a character string naming a file or a connection open
          for writing.  '""' indicates output to the console.

  append: logical. Only relevant if 'file' is a character string.  If
          'TRUE', the output is appended to the file.  If 'FALSE', any
          existing file of the name is destroyed.
```

Comment: Any idea why they wouldn't be getting the error `unused argument (path = "PREC")`? The `write.csv/write.table` function do not have `...` in their definition.

Comment: I don't know. When I try `write.csv(mtcars, "FOO", "BAR")`, I get `unused argument (path = "FOO")`. It's a good point @MrFlick, perhaps they are getting an error but didn't include it here?

Comment: That's interesting. On my Mac if I do `write.csv(mtcars, "FOO", "BAR")` I get the same error OP reports, `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : invalid 'open' argument`. (And they did include that error in the Q, I just code formatted it so it's more visible.)

Comment: Okay, for correction and clarity: on windows and linux both (using `c:/temp/` and `/tmp`, respectively), `write.csv(mtcars, "c:/temp", "AB")` errs with `invalid 'open' argument`, and `write.csv(mtcars, path="c:/temp", "AB")` errs with `unused argument (path = "c:/temp")`. I suggest one takeaway is that the OP is either not reproducible or is inadvertently hiding something relevant to discovering other problems.